# Omniture PageName tracking both custom PageName & PageURL in Omniture suite I want only custom PageName to be tracked

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

I'm facing an issue in Omniture on page load i want to track custom PageName so i add this script at bottom of the page

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"><!--
/* You may give each page an identifying name, server, and channel on
the next lines. */
pageName = "abc.com:home"
s.server=""
s.channel=""
s.pageType=""
s.prop1=""
s.prop2=""
s.prop3=""
s.prop4=""
s.prop5=""
/************* DO NOT ALTER ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE ! **************/
var s_code=s.t({pageName:pageName});if(s_code)document.write(s_code)//--></script>
<!-- End SiteCatalyst code version: H.20.3. -->
```

when ever page loads i checked through debugger tool PageName is assign with "abc.com:home" but when i checked in Omniture Suite
report & analytics -->  site content --> Pages - both custom PageName & page URL is getting tracked i want only custom PageName to be tracked in the suite please can one share there views or ideas how to get rid off with page URL.

Comment: firstly, is there any reason you are setting `pageName` like this? if you just do `s.pageName='abc.com:home'` then it will record that in the `s.t()` call without having to pass it that. Also, when you pass it like that to `s.t()` it makes it temporary. It will record the `pageName` on that hit but then erase it. Which brings me to my next point: You aren't seeing both URL and pageName value in the reports solely because of this code. This code by itself will produce one request with "abc.com:home" for page name. So you must have more going on in your code than you've shown..

Comment: .. perhaps something in your `s_code.js` file making a 2nd request. Or another `s.t()` call on the page somewhere, etc..

Comment: Hi Crayon thank you for your response
1.yup my customer requested for custom page name for all the pages through out the site. We are using a CMS tool for the site above code is hard coded in master template
2. yes I'm calling another s.t() on page load to capture other events,prop,evar..
3. If i pass s.PageName="abc.com:home" whenever I'm calling another s.t() PageName is getting captured in another s.t() to reduce duplication of PageName I'm passing it as parameter.
4. I also cross checked with other debugging tools only in one beacon I'm passing pagename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> Hi Crayon thank you for your response 1.yup my customer requested for
>   custom page name for all the pages through out the site. We are using
>   a CMS tool for the site above code is hard coded in master template 2.
>   yes I'm calling another s.t() on page load to capture other
>   events,prop,evar.. 3. If i pass s.PageName="abc.com:home" whenever I'm
>   calling another s.t() PageName is getting captured in another s.t() to
>   reduce duplication of PageName I'm passing it as parameter. 4. I also
>   cross checked with other debugging tools only in one beacon I'm
>   passing pagename

Okay so the reason you are seeing both pageName value and URL in your pages reports is because you have two `s.t()` calls, and only 1 of them has a value for `s.pageName`. You said you are passing `pageName` value to avoid getting the page counted twice. Well it's already happening, because you are using two `s.t()` calls. Since you do not specify a `pageName` in the 2nd one, the URL is the default.

The ideal solution is to restructure your code to only have one `s.t()` call. You said you are working with a CMS. So ideally you should have your `s_code.js` script tag in a global header include.  then you should have one `s.t()` call in a global footer include. You could also put **global** vars in the footer section (or within `s_code.js` > `s_doPlugins` function). Then in between those two is where you would put any page specific custom code. It seems to me that you are already kinda doing this.. but you just need to remove the first `s.t()` call.

If for whatever reason you cannot achieve the ideal solution, you should instead [make use of **`s.tl()`**](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/function_tl.html) for the 2nd request. To use `s.tl()`, you would do something like this:

```
s.prop1='foo';
s.eVar1='bar';
s.events='event1';
s.linkTrackVars='prop1,eVar1,events';
s.linkTrackEvents='event1';
s.tl(true,'o','description');
```

Basically, any props, eVars and events you want to track in `s.tl` call will need to be declared in `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents`.

**NOTE**: You should really strive for the ideal solution. It's not just the pages report that can get inflated. Any other vars you set will get inflated too. Also, Adobe's payment model is to charge for every single request made to their server, so your customer will likely not like the fact that you are doubling their bill by doing this.

The `s.tl` method is by no means ideal, but it is better than what you are doing now. as it will reduce report inflation, and `s.tl` requests cost less than `s.t` requests.

Comment: thank you very much Crayon for your valuable information. I will call only one s.t() request through out the page.

Comment: Hi Crayon I have one more doubt, if we sending a s.tl() request without s.PageName in it, does PageName by default will assign to that request?
As you said now I'm sending only one s.t() request though out the page but when I'm navigating to other page i have to capture some events so I'm using s.tl() for that but when i checked in Httpfox PageName is fired whenever s.tl() is called so again PageName is getting duplicated.

Comment: @arun408 an `s.tl` call will grab the current `pageName` value, yes. This is so Adobe can associate the event with the page the event happened on. `pageName` (or default URL if not specified) from an `s.tl` call does NOT inflate your pages report.

Comment: Also, if my answer solved your issues, please mark solved (click the check next to the answer) :)